# What does the below performance review statement mean?

Tags: performance-reviews, teamwork

During the performance review, I got this review: "his job was good but he is mostly an implementer".

**What actions can be taken to improve on this?**

Comment: This is an excellent question you should ask the person who gave the comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. This is meant to show you an "area of improvement" or a "weakness". "Implementation" translates to "do what has been told to do".

Apart from implementation, companies are looking for you to:

- Think of ideas
- Co-ordinate with people and teams
- Interact with your manager
- Understand processes and people
- Contribute in ways beyond your specific assigned roles and responsibilities

Doing some or all of the above will help you get a better salary, a bigger role or both.
Not doing this is what has likely got you the above statement.

A good thing to do would be ask for a meeting to discuss this, listen to what your manager has to say, ask for areas of specific improvement or concern and finish by promising to work on those areas.

Initiative is what everyone looks for!

Comment: Extra emphasis on "talk to your manager". Understand what (s)he expects or desires you to do beyond "implementing".